# Why does Scanner#nextInt inside for loop keep throwing an exception?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have been learning JAVA and i have a small doubt about the code :

```
class apple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] num = new int[3];

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {

            try {
                num[i] = input.nextInt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out
                    .println("Invalid number..assigning default value 20");
            num[i] = 20;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(num[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have written small program to handle exception, if user input is not Int throw an exception and assign default value.
If i put scanner statement inside for loop, it works fine, but if i take it outside its assign the same value at which exception was thrown i.e i am entering char rather than int.
But if i enter all integers it assign correct values in array.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

I hope u guys have understood my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Scanner#nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) doesn't advance past the input if it fails to parse an integer, so if you keep calling it after failure, it will keep trying to parse same input again, throwing `InputMismatchException`.

You can call [`Scanner#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--), ignoring the string it returns, in your `catch` block to skip the invalid input:

```
try {
    num[i] = input.nextInt();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out
            .println("Invalid number..assigning default value 20");
    num[i] = 20;
    input.next();
}
```

Comment: IS this what you mean, it still carry forward the same value and throws an exception..

`try {

num[i] = input.nextInt();
    
}
 catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Wrong value. PLease try again..");    
num[i] = input.nextInt();
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
        try
        {
            num[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ip)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid number..assigning default value 20");
            num[i] = 20;
            input.next();
        }
```

Comment: +1 but you should add some explanation of your _code_.

Answer (score 0):

A better code can be  that you can check that whether the next value is integer or not , So you don't even need to catch exceptions:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] num = new int[3];

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) 
     {
             if(input.hasNextInt())
             {
                  num[i] = input.nextInt();
             }

            else
            {
                System..out.println("non integer value.. will assign it default value 20");
                num[i]=20;
                input.next();
            }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {

        System.out.println(num[i]);
    }


  }
```